# Finding the integer average in a char array

Tags: java

So im having trouble creating this function that has to find the integer average of a char array.

This is my array char[]letters = {'A', 'B' , 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'};

Im trying to type cast to find the integer average like A= 32 j= 74. adding the integer value and turning it back in a character but am stuck at the moment.

```
/********************************************************************************
 This function will calculate the integer average of characters in the array
********************************************************************************/
public static void average( char [] letters )
{
     int total = 0;

     char mean;


     total = total + letters[letters.length];
     mean = (char)total / letters.length;

     System.out.println("The value is " + average( letters) );
}
```

Comment: Are you supporting accented characters in ISO-LATIN-1 or Unicode?

Comment: You can't store Unicode in a char.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
 total = total + letters[letters.length];
```

This operation adds the value past the end of the array to `total`, triggering an exception.

You need a loop here:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i != letters.length ; i++)
    total += letters[i];
```

You can also use the `for`-`in` loop, like this:

```
for (char ch : letters)
    total += ch;
```

You are also casting `total` instead of casting the result of the division:

```
mean = (char)total / letters.length;
```

should be replaced with

```
mean = (char)(total / letters.length); // Note the added parentheses
```

Comment: so the loops stops when it cannot equal 10. so i wouldnt need to typecast?

Comment: @javip No, you do not need a cast. The loop will stop once `i` reaches the end of the array, no matter how many items you pass.

Comment: @javip You can use the other kind of `for` loop as well, take a look at my edit.

Comment: hmm will the total be turned back to a char because of the +=letters[i]?

Comment: @javip No, the `mean` needs to be cast, like this: `mean = (char)(total / letters.length);`

Comment: yeah thanks i was getting a loss of precision error without the paren

Answer (score 1):

First of all- your method is recursive and it will break.
I suppose you want to cast chars into their decimal ascii codes. Try this:

```
public static int average( char [] letters )
{
     int total = 0;

     for(int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++){
       total += (int)letters[i];
     }

     return total / letters.length; //or cast it back to char if you prefer
}
```

Comment: well since mines a void function just s.o.p instead of the return right?

Comment: Sure, why not. Or you can just print out the value in the main method (assuming you are working with a console program) like this: System.out.println(average(targetedCharacterArray)+"");

Answer (score 0):

Is this an exercise on how to do this for the sake of doing it? If not, use a Character array and use .digit().

If so, then you are on the right track, but my first thought is to just loop through, subtracting the appropriate value to change the ascii chars to numbers, maybe stick them in a new array, and loop again to average.

Honestly I don't see how you are even attempting this with 0 loops.